# c++ - Segmentation fault with boost::filesystem::directory_iterator on raspberryy

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, raspberry-pi, filesystems

I am trying to iterate throug a directory and catch all available bitmaps within a given directory.

After compiling G++6.2 and changing the SDcard on my RPI Zero I am getting Segfaults when instatiating `boost::filesystem::direcotry_iterator itr(path)`

Here is the Code throwing segfault:

```
boost::filesystem::path picturePath = "/path";

boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;

if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(picturePath))
{
    for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(picturePath); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
    {
        do somthing with the files;
    }
}
```

As the code was working before the two changes I believe that the code is still correct. But why am I getting segfaults when creating the start iterator?

Comment: Where is `end_itr` set (besides being default initialized)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it must be default-constructed. That's how input iterators usually work

Comment: @OP I think you need to post the actual code. It's also possible you get ABI conflicts (building with incompatible flags/compiler/library versions)

Comment: @shee What do you mean with ABI conflicts? My problem is that the code was running before I switched to g++ 6.2 and changed the SD card. Therefore I guess there is no issue with the code but also can't imagine that the new gdb or SD card has that kind of impact on the code.

Comment: That right there is your smoking gun: g++6.2 no doubt changed the ABI. Google it (hint: simply compile Boost with the _same_ compiler and flags)